# Given a trigonometric equation, use the identity and unit circle to solve $ 2 \tan (\theta) - \cot (\theta) -1=0$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, trigonometric-integrals

Solve the equation :

$$ 2 \tan (\theta) - \cot (\theta) -1=0$$

I solved this equation and got the value of $\tan (\theta)$ as $\frac{-1}{2}$ and $ -1 $ ,

I want to write its general formula .Kindly check if my answer is correct and help me to write the general formula in case the value is $\frac{-1}{2}$.
Sorry because I don't know how to use latex

Comment: You will get responses if you show your work. You can learn MathJax here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I will take that into consideration in future

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2\tan(\theta)-\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}-1=0$$

$$ 2\tan^2(\theta)- \tan(\theta)-1=0$$

Suppose $x = \tan(\theta)$

$$2x^2-x-1 = 0 $$

$$x = \frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(2)(-1)}}{2(2)}$$

$$x = \frac{1 \pm 3}{4} $$

$$ x = \tan(\theta)=  1, -\frac{1}{2}$$

Note :

$ \theta = \arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and tan is positive in 1st and 3rd quadrant. So, general solution will be $$ \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi , ~ n \in  \mathbb{Z} $$
for second solution $ \theta = \arctan(-\frac{1}{2})$,   tan is negative in 2nd and 4th quadrant. So general solution:

$$ \theta = \arctan(- \frac{1}{2})+n\pi, n \in  \mathbb{Z}  $$

Comment: Oh so I have to use inverse in this case

Comment: Yes inverse tangent